# Java: Create Drawable from UTF8 String

Tags: java, android, image, drawable

I have the following code:

```
public void onSuccess(String response) {
    Log.i("EOH",response);
    Drawable d = null;
    Object content=response.getBytes();
    InputStream is = (InputStream)content;
    d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");

    ImageView captcha = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    captcha.setImageDrawable(d);
}
```

Here is the response string I'm getting (from LogCat):

> 08-12 11:33:52.223: INFO/EOH(10244): PNG
>
> 08-12 11:33:52.223: INFO/EOH(10244):  08-12 11:33:52.223:
>   INFO/EOH(10244): ������
>   IHDR������d������2������%Wéé����IDAThíéSgÇÏÙM²\R 08-12
>   11:33:52.223: INFO/EOH(10244): *h=¨xß-¥:Ni}Ñ?ª¯:}¡S+µ3ötÇàÕ
>   *Äî#$a7ÙÝd¾H'
>
>   £²$8ÝÏ«äÙßîóï{��¦,²Ê2)Ë��¦,²`Ê2)Ë��¦,²`Ê2)Ë��¦,²@¬dg¡ä<¯ð°BsìJvVHÖpüõ­Ðí°I·xH÷1×ÁJkÅâbQ§3PÅKãôÊp)¬¬{áö°¡0ªÄR¬>MÎý0uýËâ/|ÖÊÌÊöðèCUW��l»cëaç~­¸ÈIVRKþ>wKÑgX]góY¼¢*
>   12³²Å{zB\o«&0��t]oìÅ¹¢³ß}§êªYXiêwq;�� ä
>   08-12 11:33:52.223: INFO/EOH(10244):
>   I.}#Bh+»¹=ÒNF3Ø}��-ÞSíë`Aá¯N]*ô5q·¿^¾0þÅÝW.sÌ$§åÍJ.¦^ïtl;P¸@¸tãOèPr~D
>   08-12 11:33:52.223: INFO/EOH(10244):
>   fÝÆFÄ ?¸1û��¬¡KÓdMÔÈ)��pìaç~��_Ø@lðU|¸ïkâ²g·\³ .©¤+�� .[kóÙqû¥Ò#Îç¼g2G¥ñË?^j½:}=(cÎCé«d!ÔóÉpºqLPrÞÐ¨ÎxiÔHòE¾©
>   H#}ÂÀ{
>   ��tDHýQcÁö¬J¯ÅÝÀÔ¤`TY��uÖ*,H_EÕ3µÝ|ïÉkM#Q}Â_��¤Ê©%¦¤·Ê��,Áä>Á4yµÁ^}3ô×PÜ/©RLwDáov]\IaÔIÏ§��Ðy|7ÜÖÅ÷4q®#ÎsÐ¨<~+t;óF¡Ô%¦¤ ÄtÐiÆ>ä$9;nÏq¦øùóçs}Âç¡ä,GtFGènWj½rºlXôóªð½&3qofê
>   08-12 11:33:52.223: INFO/EOH(10244):
>   IÎY\¤s[6¯klÕÖr�� qºÊê{*ôÀNÇ¶­l`â¨I®!¬©
>   %ÃÝ|/ðþÙýèáÙÃèßq¤*brPýK=S��wÂmAiÔE:wséKÏ§XÖ-"����GxV;B¨ÙtÚÓÜâ=UJ¤¢½*c{±ä��dM+KQ9UFcô¨<~yòZ*G~6¥UÖJ;n©q��øÌu4SA7ßFRp£½ÆMºl¸5©+CqP£0ª.{Ó3_ÅýSÝg­ÈüÒ%¤äÊ@%]qÖÛúôiºöÓô!Ñß'ìá>YÞ4ó#!t°pßËøt¦>/i»ý6{s*1ÓÍ÷f¶üÜsÂ¨tËh×dbÅ
>   ´ 46!OtõÈêî))(��ÓeéÂVJ~EK.{y;î4°u
>   lÝâv¯ÅóMÙ×SòÌ¨4Q¢¢&p®MÌ¬Ä_gî§DlwlÙÇíÎ:��³¬·U÷ÇÄ^ôÇ5Ðö49ÉÂtAjeeÕcj��¾WèlXLy)ïÛk.µøÅÀlrNÓu'Éù¬ë.z¦¶?öüN¸MÖä¬EE,^��ÅW½¬¥Zkó­ßRßwçÛÆå
>   ��J£U¶ÊT£®ëÊ��°9ü4´*NóË
>   5¶uM;³Ròe|XÑ��è>Õÿ;ßO\JÌ��@[¸CÓµåuºVQÞ_\IÌòª`Å¬VÜj¤qÒA'Ý#úÿüóO×uAO4Ê¼²Êñ¨ø¡fÖ{Áe��SLY0eÀe��SLY0eÀe��SLY0eÀe§~)l1+��������IEND®B`

As you can see, I'm trying to convert a String called 'response' to a Drawable object. Trouble is, the image is always blank!

Does anyone know of any way I might be able to fix this?

Many thanks in advance,

---

Edit:

This didn't work either ;(

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(String response) {
    Log.i("EOH",response);          
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes());
    Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);

    ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(response);
```

Or you could do the following, if you don't need it to be Drawable.

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(response);
ImageView captcha = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
captcha.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

**EDITED**

For online files, you can use this:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is)
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the response - just got back from my lunch hour - I'll try that out and get back to you...

Comment: Hey, tried to integrate your code, and it didn't work ;( Image just shows up blank...

Comment: Wait - is this a local file or a file from the web?

Comment: It's the string response from the web. Sorry should have been clearer.

Comment: Hey, I tried your edit - still doesn't work... (Please see my edit)

Comment: Are you sure the stream is returning a valid image file?

Comment: Yes, pretty sure... I wonder how could I test this? Here is the url: http://109.123.109.205/lib/simpleCaptcha/image.php

Comment: Try it out with this file:
http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwOTEwNjAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc5MTUwMw@@._V1_SX81.jpg

Comment: Referral Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwOTEwNjAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc5MTUwMw@@._V1_SX81.jpg" on this server.

Reference #24.61b5d50.1313162319.361598a

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Well, basically just try it out with any image you can find on the web.

Comment: I tried it with http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/amd-logo-106x59.jpg and it didn't work... ;(

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full function I'm using (doesn't work...):

```
private void captchaLoad() {
         AsyncHttpClient myClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
         PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(context);
         myClient.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);
         RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

         myClient.post("http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/amd-logo-106x59.jpg", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                Log.i("EOH",response);

                ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;
                try {
                    bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes("UTF8"));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);

                ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bm);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) {

            }
        });
     }
```